# Быстрая организация работы с *.STL файлами в Java или C#

Tags: java, c#, 3d

Подскажите какие-нибудь простые но эффективные технологии для считывания содержимого *.STL файла, обработки этого содержимого и вывода на экран в десктопном приложении. 
Есть необходимость решить мат задачу по 3D модели из файла в данном формате.

Существует ли возможность просто реализовать в визуальном представлении модели что-то на подобии ластика, чтоб убирать определённые вершины?

Comment: [Working with STL file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16389186/312041)

Comment: tym32167, там толком ничего нет. Да и вопрос задавался 6 лет назад. Я просто в надежде что кто-то этим занимался и знает прям какую крутую штуку, а так вручную что-нибудь на ковыряю старыми методами.

Comment: да судя по [описанию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)) там всё просто, но если вам прямо надо библиотеку, то [удачи тут](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=STL&type=Repositories)